# I am completely lost on the 3 if statements

Tags: javascript

So I am taking a course and was told to make a simple 3 if statement.
I am getting an error that there is an un-needed opening brace `{` at `6:23`.

I feel as though the code was correct. Am I performing 3 elses incorrectly?

```
var age = prompt("Please Enter Your Age.");
    if (age <= 17) {
        alert("Sorry you are too young to drive, powering off!");
    }  
    else if (age === 18) {
        alert("Congratulations on your first year of adult driving, drive Safe!");
    }  
    else (age >= 19) {
        alert("Powering on, drive safe!");
    }
```

Comment: Regarding your update, which is line 6? Are you using an IDE to help you discover what line is in error?

Comment: `else (age >= 19)` is an error.  `else` doesn't take a condition. It should just be `else {   }`

Comment: else (age >= 19) {
        alert("Powering on, drive safe!");
    }

Comment: Ha, good spot @Mark_M: I read it through several times! `:-)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because `else` doesn't accept a condition on its own.

It's specifically throwing this error because the parser is interpreting `(age >= 19)` as a separate statement, as in:

```
else {
    (age >= 19);
}
```

The parser isn't expecting `{` to be next in that.

```
else {
    (age >= 19) {
        alert("Powering on, drive safe!");
    }
}
```

---

To keep the condition in place, you'll have to pair `else` with another `if`, which will understand `(age >= 19)` as a condition.

```
...
else if (age >= 19) {
    alert("Powering on, drive safe!");
}
```

Or, discard the last condition. With `else` its own like this, it'll define the "default" behavior, taken when the prior `if`'s condition doesn't pass.

```
...
else {
    alert("Powering on, drive safe!");
}
```

Comment: Not sure I'll get an answer, but curious why the downvote. What have I said or done here that's incorrect?

Comment: Not sure but this was great! Thanks for answering my question, it was my first and may have been very confusing!

Comment: Downvoter here. While entirely technically correct (of course) and useful to OP, I fail to see how it will be useful to future visitors.

Comment: @PaulStenne Perhaps. I don't know if it will. The title of the question isn't very searchable currently. But, I'm at least not as convinced it won't, having posted other answers before that seemed too specific yet continue to receive votes years after. It is a basic problem, though seemed a bit more than just a typo. And, the [community is at least beginning to shift its demeanor](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).